# I don't know why it is refreshed when i activate the event in this code

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm not good at English, so please understand.

I am asking you because my web is refreshed when I activate `submitPost` event.

This is the code. and `submitPost` at line 28.

I really wonder that **why it is not refreshed when I don't call `easyHttp.post`** which is an async function and refreshed when I call `easyHttp.post`.

I've tried to put e.preventDefault() but is not working. plz help me ;(

```js
import { easyHttp } from './easyhttp3.js';
import { ui } from './ui.js';

const URLs = {
  base: "http://localhost:3000",
  getAllPosts: "/posts",
  addPost: "/posts"
};

// DOM Loaded Eventlistners
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getPosts);

// Listen for add post
document.querySelector(".post-submit").addEventListener("click", submitPost);

// get Posts
function getPosts() {
  easyHttp.get(`${URLs.base}${URLs.getAllPosts}`)
    .then(data => {
      ui.showPosts(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
};

// Submit Post
function submitPost(e) {
  const title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
  const body = document.querySelector("#body").value;

  if (title !== "" && body !== "") {
    const dataToSend = {
      title,
      body
    };
  
    easyHttp.post(`${URLs.base}${URLs.addPost}`, dataToSend)
      .then(data => {
        ui.showAlert("Post Added!", "alert alert-info");
        ui.clearFields();
        getPosts();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}
```

And It's HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Microposts</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@5.0.1/dist/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary mb-4">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MicroPosts</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container postsContainer">
    <div class="card card-body card-form">
      <h1>Say Something</h1>
      <p class="lead">What's on your mind?</p>
      <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Post Title">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <textarea id="body" class="form-control" placeholder="Post Body"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="id" value="">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success post-submit">Post It</button>
      <span class="form-end"></span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="posts"></div>
  </div>
  
  <footer class="mt-5 p-3 text-center bg-light">
    MicroPosts &copy;
  </footer>
  <script type="module" src="./src/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your HTML too please. $5 says `.post-submit` is a `button[type=submit]` or an `input[type=submit]` in a form and since you are using onclick instead of onsubmit, e.preventDefault does not prevent the form from submitting the default way with a page redirect.

Comment: @David button type is "button". and i edited to paste HTML!

Comment: @David and its my github repo. [MicroPosts](https://github.com/dev-jian/microposts)

Answer (score 0):

What I believe could be happening is that, if your html is a type `form` and the button have the type `submit`, then 2 events are fired: a `click` (from the button) and a `submit` (also from the button, but for the form)

easiest change could be:

```
document
    .querySelector(".post-submit")
    .addEventListener("submit", submitPost);
```

this will intercept the `submit` (either from click or from a possible enter) and handle it (remember to add the `e.preventDefault` if needed.)

**Further Resources**

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-form/

Comment: I edited my question to paste the HTML. It has no form tag and button type is "button".

Comment: and its my github repo. [MicroPosts](https://github.com/dev-jian/microposts)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using babel & webpack.

before now I used to use live server which is VS code extension,

now I'm using webpack-dev-server and compile with babel to solve this problem.

I don't know why it works, so I have to figure it out, what's happening inside.

Thank You guys and I update my repo so that everyone could reference the solution.